# How do I move shared components to a separate folder?

Tags: typescript, components, vuejs3

I have the following project structure.

```
folder/
├─ projectA/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ views/
│  │  │  ├─ HomeView.vue
│  ├─ package.json
├─ projectB/
├─ shared/
│  ├─ HelloWorld.vue
```

**ProjectA** and **ProjectB** are independent projects created with the help of a command :

`-> vue create ...`

**shared -**  a folder that should contain only files.vue - components that can be used in both project A and project B.

The **HomeView.vue** (from **projectA**) component tries to use the **HelloWorld.vue** (from **shared** folder) component.

**HomeView.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from '../../../shared/HelloWorld.vue' // @ is an alias to /src

export default defineComponent({
   name: 'HomeView',
   components: {
       HelloWorld
   }
})
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
})
</script>
```

If **HelloWorld.vue** the vue component in **projectA** in the "components" folder everything will work (the import path will change slightly). But when I try to output this component to the **shared** folder, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../shared/HelloWorld.vue:37:33
TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
    35 |
    36 | <script lang="ts">
  > 37 | import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
       |                                 ^^^^^
    38 |
    39 | export default defineComponent({
    40 |   name: 'HelloWorld',
```

How do I fix the error and make the components that are outside the project work correctly?

*From the documentation:*

*“Why can’t people use my .vue file directly? Isn’t that the simplest way to share components?”
It’s true, you can share .vue files directly, and anyone using a Vue build containing the Vue compiler can consume it immediately.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explanatory:

```
  TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

  > 37 | import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
```

In the shared folder, there is no `vue` dependency so HelloWorld can't import it. If you check any vue component library published on npm you will see they have a `package.json` file in which you can find a vue dependency.

I would suggest you simply copy the component inside your project OR you take the longer, but much more rewarding path of creating your very own [npm package](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm) with vue components. You can start [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-publish-a-vuejs-component-on-npm-aa703714b512). (*Disclaimer*: I didn't follow the steps in the article but it looks alright at first glance and it should give you a general idea of the process)

Comment: I was able to get the application running by manually copying node_modules from projectA to the shared folder. I didn't create the package.json files and stuff. Why does it work? Should I initialize the folder folder as a vue project?

Comment: Yes, I have seen a solution with a private npm package. But it would be more convenient to use it as just a third-party file, as in my case.

From the documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html
“Why can’t people use my .vue file directly? Isn’t that the simplest way to share components?” It’s true, you can share .vue files directly, and anyone using a Vue build containing the Vue compiler can consume it immediately.

Comment: Read until the end of the paragraph. It clearly says:
"Properly packaging your SFC for distribution via npm enables your component to be shared in a way which is ready to use everywhere!"

Comment: You will run into dependencies issues (you currently have no way to track dependencies inside shared folder). On top of that, imagine you want to deploy projectA. What will the path "import HelloWorld from '../../../shared/HelloWorld.vue' " resolve to? Well, nothing, because you are pointing to a specific file available in your local environment. Once deployed, you will end up with an error. There is no shared folder on the server. And if you decide to include it inside the projectA (/project/shared) then you might as well copy the HelloWorld inside it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the npm package will be the best solution.

Comment: I am glad this convinced you. :) You will learn A LOT going down the npm road. Also, keep in mind that when you import HelloWorld.vue the way you did, the project using it has no information about the npm packages it needs for HelloWorld.vue component to function properly. Example: let us say HelloWorld.vue needs some CSS library like TailwindCSS. Where is this information stored? It isn't. HelloWorld.vue simply imports it. So you will end up with error(s) in your project and need to manually add missing library.